# JQuery iteration with object

Tags: jquery, object, iteration, structure

I hve this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="S1" />
<input type="text" id="S2" />
<input type="text" id="S3" />
<input type="text" id="S4" /> 
<input type="text" id="S5" />
```

How can I achieve this pseudo-code:

```
var qData{};
for (i = 1; i == 5; i++) {
        qData.qBidS + i = $("#S" + i).val;
    }
```

At the end I want is a set of 5 qData:
qData.S1, qData.S2, qData.S3, qData.S4, qData.S5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var qData = {};
for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    qData["qBidS" + i] = $("#S" + i).val();
}
```

Problems:

- Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), there is no `value` property of jQuery object.
- Use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) and use string as per your requirement.
- Condition should be `i <= 5` not `i == 5`

Comment: @Satpal: Thanks for this simple yet elegant solution. Works like  charm.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PAbM/)***</kbd>

*jQuery*

```
$('#textBoxCover input').each(function () {
     qData.push($(this).val());
});
```

Hope it helps..!!